How to implement a proper fuzzy search in Flutter (dart)?
I did research a lot before posting here and found 2 libraries fuzzy and distance, tried both but are not giving good results.
It is incredible the way the sort is working although my search term is matching exactly 70% of text, I still see other stuff on top.
Anyway, this is my current implementation, which again is not accurate:

int levenshtein(String s, String t) {
  if (s == t) return 0;
  if (s.isEmpty) return t.length;
  if (t.isEmpty) return s.length;

  List<int> v0 = List<int>.filled(t.length + 1, 0);
  List<int> v1 = List<int>.filled(t.length + 1, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < t.length + 1; i < i++) v0[i] = i;

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    v1[0] = i + 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
      int cost = (s[i] == t[j]) ? 0 : 1;
      v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, min(v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < t.length + 1; j++) {
      v0[j] = v1[j];
    }
  }

  return v1[t.length];
}

List<T> fuzzySearch<T>(
    List<T> list, String Function(T item) getProperty, String searchTerm) {
  final lowerSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

  // Sort by score (lower score means more similar)
  return [...list]..sort((a, b) {
      final aScore = levenshtein(getProperty(a).toLowerCase(), lowerSearchTerm);
      final bScore = levenshtein(getProperty(b).toLowerCase(), lowerSearchTerm);

      return aScore.compareTo(bScore);
    });
}

// Some example usage below


class _SomeItem {
  final String name;

  _SomeItem(this.name);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  List<_SomeItem> items = [
    _SomeItem('banana johnes'),
    _SomeItem('other random stuff'),
    _SomeItem('whatever'),
    _SomeItem('bendana'),
    _SomeItem('buonana'),
    _SomeItem('mr bean'),
    _SomeItem('dandy trout'),
    _SomeItem('don john'),
  ];

  final searchResult = fuzzySearch(items, (item) => item.name, 'banana');

  for (var element in searchResult) {
    print(element.name);
  }
}

Nice thing is that it is generic and you can pass any object, and a function to read the text property based on  which you want to fuse search.
If you run my code above you will get back this result which is weird.
In this example it is not as weird as with my real data, where I see on top of the list items with 3 characters and I search with 7 8 words that have 2 words and better matching are left lower in list..
bendana
buonana
mr bean
banana johnes
whatever
don john
dandy trout
other random stuff

I expect banana johnes to be first as it matches 1 word
How can I improve this code so it is more accurate?

Share search widget related code for better understanding.

I have shared all that is necessary + steps to reproduce. THe widget is not relevant because will only disiplay a list of the text that am printing in my example
